# Perspective Compensation when Measuring Distances on an Image with a known reference distance

Tags: opencv, math, image-processing, computer-vision, perspectivecamera

I am trying to calculate the real world distance of an arbitrary line drawn along the field of view from a one point perspective, single camera setup.

I will have a known distance running parallel. How can I find the compensation factor I need to apply to the pixel length of the measuring line?

[image]

Do I have to take into account the distance from the vanishing point, as the length per pixel increases the nearer you get to the vanishing point? Do I need to use the gradient of the known line to give me a rate of change?

Comment: An image would help. Perhaps you can upload to imgur and edit your question to provide the link, then someone with enough rep. can include the image. If you know the vanishing point, then you can use the cross ratio to compute relative distances, i.e. ratios between real world distances. I doubt whether that known distance parallel will provide any more information. For a generic projective transformation it won't.

Comment: Just some keyword dropping: You may be able to use cross ratios to unentangle the projective relationships of points in an image, see this (short) topic: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/79510/115115

Comment: I've been reading up on cross ratios, this seems to only help if measuring at right angles to the view to vanishing point. Is this correct or am I just being dense?

Comment: Anything you will be able to do here will only work under the assumption that the road is completely flat. If it goes up and down a bit, you won't be able to quantify distances unless you have multiple cameras and can determine the actual distance.

Answer (score 2):

A good study on this and similar problems can be found in Antonio Criminisi's papers and Ph.D. thesis on single-view metrology. [This](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67278) is a good link to start, and the whole paperdump is [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~criminis/pubbli.html)